# spark-java MatcherFilter NullPointerException from jar

Tags: maven, jar, spark-java

I'm working on an spark(2.3) web app in java with jade templates.
The solder structure looks something like this:

```
src-
 |-main
   |-java
   |   |-my.java.class
   |-resources
       |-public
       |      |-js
       |-templates
       |      |-start.jade
```

Main class sample looks like this:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    port(4050);
    staticFileLocation("public");

    get("/", (req, res) -> {
        return new ModelAndView(new HashMap<>(), "start");
    }, new JadeTemplateEngine());

    get("/test", (req, res) -> {
        return "<b>TEST</b>";
    });
```

As I run this app through IDE (Intellij ore Eclipse)  all is ok, Every route can be opened and all templates are render fine, but when I build a jar file only the pure HTML works fine (localhost:4050/test) by trying open a jade template route server throws this:

```
ERROR spark.webserver.MatcherFilter - java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.Reader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at de.neuland.jade4j.template.ClasspathTemplateLoader.getReader(ClasspathTemplateLoader.java:26)
    at spark.template.jade.loader.SparkClasspathTemplateLoader.getReader(SparkClasspathTemplateLoader.java:48)
    at de.neuland.jade4j.lexer.Lexer.<init>(Lexer.java:37)
    at de.neuland.jade4j.parser.Parser.<init>(Parser.java:85)
    at de.neuland.jade4j.JadeConfiguration.createTemplate(JadeConfiguration.java:83)
    at de.neuland.jade4j.JadeConfiguration.getTemplate(JadeConfiguration.java:56)
    at spark.template.jade.JadeTemplateEngine.render(JadeTemplateEngine.java:77)
    at com.nokia.tasks.Tasker.Main.lambda$8(Main.java:134)
    at spark.RouteImpl$1.handle(RouteImpl.java:58)
    at spark.webserver.MatcherFilter.doFilter(MatcherFilter.java:162)
    at spark.webserver.JettyHandler.doHandle(JettyHandler.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:517)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:302)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:245)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceAndRun(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:572)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Could any one help?
BR 
Wojtek

Comment: BTW in jar file all templates are presents

Comment: Try to open your `jar` file in some file explorer which you use for regular compressed `zip` files (it should open it) and check whether all your templates are packaged into your jar. If they are then check if you are using correct paths to access them as they might be packaged into different folder structure in final jar. If you use `maven` have a look at `assembly-plugin` which should help you maintain structure. If they are not included then again assembly-plugin is helpful

Comment: All templates file are in place (in jar of course) the path seems to be fine to. I'll try various setting of  assembly-plugin, but with no luck :(.
Funny thing is, that I download an old jar working on server,(all the time) and as I try run it was the same (can't find the template)??

Comment: Additional comment; I notice that on server run java version 1.8.0_66 and on my local is 1.8.0_91. Maybe this is the case?

Comment: another comment: all builds fine as I build it on linux platform. the same folder (src) and pom??

Comment: It shouldn't have nothing to do with java version as your local JVM is higher version and java has backwards compatibility plus it's just minor security release. Can you show the code where you load the template (if you do it manually) because that error seems to be related to framework loading template from the classpath using it's name. Here have a look at the source code of the `ClasspathTemplateLoader` (third error): http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/de.neuland-bfi/jade4j/0.4.0/de/neuland/jade4j/template/ClasspathTemplateLoader.java